# How to cancel TextBox_Validating event from another method c#

Tags: c#

I've constraint on `txtDate_Validating`,  if the user left the `txtDate.text` empty the message box appears!

But still the message appears if the user close the form!!

So.. how can I cancel the `textbox_Validating` event from `Form_Closing` event?

Thanks...

Comment: Please show What have you done..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is totally unclear. Can you show your work as well? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: 1) please show some code 
2) use ctrl+k to high-light the code

Comment: Well of course it does. To close the form you have to leave the textbox...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    try
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);

        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

        // Confirm user wants to close
        switch (MessageBox.Show(this, "\tAre you sure you want to close ?", "Closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
        {
            case DialogResult.No:
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    finally
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure what the question is about?

Comment: Yes, he wants to distort the validation of the textbox upon closing the form. I've provided a solution to close the form, in turn ending the validation of the textbox

Comment: Should kill the validate event in the default case as well, to answer the implied question. Though I'm assuming some sort of save action also needs to be skipped as well.

Comment: I don't see where you are preventing the textBox_Validating event from showing `MessageBox` Did you tried it?

Comment: Your solution stops the form being closed until the textbox has some entry.

Comment: This force closes the form, in turn killing any running process of the form

Comment: Before `OnFormClosing` will fire, `Validating` event will be fired. Did you tried it?

Comment: I have tried force closing the form and was working fine, but not tried with killing the validation process

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is not so simple.
The validating event in a control raises before the lost focus event, so **before** the user can close the window.
If I were you, I would use an [ErrorProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a MessageBox warning.

In this way if the user closes the form, there are no annoying messages on the screen.